# How many cores can each VM have with free ESXi?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, licensing, hypervisor

I am a bit confused about VMware's licensing with vSphere Hypervisor (the free one). I have a server with 2 X5650 Intel processors which have 6 cores each and 12 threads. What would be the maximum number of cores I can allocate to a single VM (guest) with vSphere Hypervisor?

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault.  Can you provide the version of VMWare along with the actual hypervisor.  ESX, ESXi, etc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you're limited to 8 vCPU's per VM.

Comment: Yes, 8 vCPU is a limitation. In addition, nice guide comparing free ESXi vs paid. https://www.vmwareblog.org/esxi-free-buy-esxi-anyway/